# Finding the derivative at a particular point

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

So I've got this question and I'm not 100% if I've actually answered it correctly, would be appreciated if you can check it and tell me whether its correct if not can you tell me where I went wrong and where I can improve thanks! :)

**Question**

Find the derivative of the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}), &x \neq 0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$

at $x=0$

**Working**

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})$

*Apply squeeze theorem.

$-1\leq\lim_{h\to 0}h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})\leq1$

$\therefore \lim_{h\to 0}h^2(\frac{1}{-1})\leq\lim_{h\to 0}h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})\leq\lim_{h\to 0}h^2(\frac{1}{1})$

$0\leq\lim_{h\to 0}h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})\leq 0$

$\implies \lim_{h\to 0}h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})=0$

Comment: How did it go to 0 suddenly? Till sandwhich theorem, it was fine. I don't get it how did you made it $\in(0,0)$.

Comment: It is Ok, since $\left| h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})\right|\le h^2$ and $h^2 \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh $\lim_{h\to 0} h^2 = 0$ does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes @JamesBlair. I just failed to notice that h. My bad

Comment: It'd be clearer if you said $-1 \le \sin(\frac{1}{h}) \le 1$ and then multiplied through by $h^2$ and then took the limit. IMO, of course.

Comment: @Nick so it answered the question?

Comment: THere is another mistake: after "Working", the first line should only have $h$ to the first power - one of the $h$'s in the square gets cancelled by the denominator. That carries through to the rest of the calculation, but I have not verified whether or not it invalidates the argument. You may have to worry about approaching 0 from above and from below separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the function is differentiable away from $x=0$. Therefore, away from $0$, we have $$f'(x) = 2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \cos\left( \frac{1}{x} \right).$$ Applying the squeeze theorem to $$2x \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right),$$ we see that the limit is indeed zero. Moreover, for $\cos(1/x)$, the limit does not exist. Therefore, the derivative is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: I fail to see how your argument has anything to do with finding the derivative of the function at x=0. What you seem to be doing is differentiating $f$ elsewhere and then making limit considerations for $x \rightarrow 0$. But this has *nothing* to do with actually differentiating the function at $0$. In addition, how can you apply the squeeze theorem to $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x \rightarrow 0$? That limit does not exist. This is a case of a function that is differentiable everywhere but where the derivative is *not* continuous at $0$.

Comment: @Ingix Thank you for that, I have up-voted your answer. Very detailed, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The work shown in the original posting goes in the right direction. However, there are some mistakes in it that are partially already covered in the comments, but a very important one is not (although it is inconsequential here):

It is correct that what needs to be evaluated is

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
$$

but this is

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h\sin(\frac1h)
$$

In the work of the original posting this was incorrectly evaluated as $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h^2\sin(\frac1h)$.

In the original posting when applying the squeeze theorem, the term $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h^2\sin(\frac1h)$ was always in the middle of the 'squeeze', even in the starting line

$$
-1 \le \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h^2\sin(\frac1h) \le 1
$$

But this makes no sense, because you are already making statements about the limit, which you are just about to show (but haven't yet) that it is 0. In other words, how do you know that that limit is between -1 and 1?

The squeeze theorem wants you to put the *elements* of the sequence under consideration between elements of other sequences that are hopefully easier to evaluate and hopefully converging against the same limit. So you have to ask yourself: How can I squeeze $h\sin(\frac1h)$ between sequences that converge to $0$?

What you do know is

$$
-1 \le \sin(\frac1h) \le 1
$$

or alternatively written

$$
|\sin(\frac1h)| \le 1.
$$

If you multiply both sides by the positive $|h|$ ($h$ can't be zero, obviously), you get

$$
|h\sin(\frac1h)| = |\sin(\frac1h)||h| \le |h|,
$$

or alternatively

$$
-|h| \le h\sin(\frac1h) \le |h|
$$

Since $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} |h| = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} -|h| = 0$, this successfully squeezes $h\sin(\frac1h)$ between two sequences converging to 0, so you finally get what you wanted to prove:

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h\sin(\frac1h) = 0.
$$

Of course, this is a very detailed explanation. Most people are satisfied with something that is already stated in the comments, like "$|h\sin(\frac1h)| \le |h|$ and $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} |h|=0$, so $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h\sin(\frac1h) = 0$ follows".